# JavaScript Library in a Spring/Java Web Project for building a Excel-like Data Grid with DB audit control hooks

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, excel, spring

Appreciate recommendation for a JavaScript Library for building an Excel-like Grid in a Java Spring Web App.
Key Features:

1. Excel like Data Grid (no formula or math support)
2. A per-row audit trail of each change (Web Service call backs)
3. View (& Restore) historical data/audit trail alongside/below each row

Under Evaluation:

- http://handsontable.com/
- PrimeFaces
- jqGrid 4.7
- Angular Js
- GWT
- SlickGrid
- ExtJS

FYI - I will make the source code of my solution available to the person with the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've been learning and using AngularJS recently and really like it, I think you could put together something that would do that quicker than what you would think.

But that is just opinion, I have not used any of the other ones (apart from a look into GWT a few times)

One thing you might want to try is to keep an eye on Stack Overflow to see how many problems people have with each one and how quickly the community answers the problems!!